# An agent far from the destination does not move | Nav Mesh

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently using NavMesh to walk the agent on a large floor.
The large floor is about 2000m x 2000m.

Agents are generated by **Instantiate ()**.
If the generated agent is close to the destination, the agent will move.
And, conversely, if the created agent is far from the destination, the agent will stop.
When I manually move an agent generated at a distance close to the destination to a distant place (by editing transform.position), the agent walks toward the destination.

If the agent is close to the target, it works.
With the code below.

```
    GameObject target;
    NavMeshAgent NavMeshAgent;
    void Update()
    {
       NavMeshAgent.SetDestination(target.transform.position);
    }
```

This is a generic code that walks towards the target of the NavMeshAgent.

As mentioned earlier, if the distance between the agent and the target is short, the agent moves toward the target.

Is this caused by using **NavMeshAgent.SetDestination** with **Update**?

Suddenly this problem hit me so I don't know what to do.
Please tell me if you know the answer.

Thank you

Comment: Isn't Update called every frame? It would mean that you try to calculate path to the target that often. Probably it cannot complete the calculation before the next Update. Can you try calling it less frequently?

Comment: From the documentation: SetDestination - Sets or updates the destination thus triggering the calculation for a new path
Thats definitely something you don't want to do that oftern. Especially for multiple game objects at the same time. Try greater intervals and shrink them down as the distance between the game objects is shorter.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

>> Try greater intervals and shrink them down as the distance between the game objects is shorter.

I do not understand this meaning well.
Does this mean that the smaller the distance between the agent and the destination, the finer the calculation?

Also, I run the agent **NavMeshAgent.SetDestination()** every few seconds, but the agent still doesn't try to move.

I'm sorry! I forgot to say it!
The agent is generated by **Instantiate()**.

I will edit the question later.